# What running applications and services are safe to turn off?

Tags: applications, settings, task-management, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Knowing which applications to stop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2906/knowing-which-applications-to-stop)

I just got a used Nexus One and I see a lot of running services and applications.  I'm wondering what negative impact there would be if I just started switching them off?

For example, obviously, I don't want to mess with "Calendar," but what about "Calendar Storage?" If I install Handcent SMS, do I still need the Messaging-related services/applications?  Same for Media: if I install Winamp, do I still need those?

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/1465

Answer (score 3):

Calendar depends on Calendar Storage; Handcent still relies on the device's services for receiving messages; and I would guess that even if Winamp doesn't rely on Media, your wallpaper or notification sounds or something else does.

I would mostly leave these "System" services alone.  If you have battery trouble, it's likely due to user-installed apps.

Comment: Pretty sure that Winamp (and most other players) still use the device's Media database to save having to rescan everything themselves.